# Killing forked child kills parent?

Tags: c, linux, process, ipc

I am into this weird behaviour where I have my main program and a forked child. They are piped like this(the numbers are file descriptors):

```
 ___parent___
|            |                     ____child_____
| 0 stdin    |                    |              |
| 1 pipe1[1]----------.           |  1 stdout    |
| 2 pipe2[1]----------.\          |  2 stderr    |
|____________|         \`----------> 3 pipe1[0]  | 
                        `----------> 5 pipe2[0]  |
                                  |______________|
```

So parent gets input from *stdin* but redirects *stdout* and *stderr* to two pipes. The child has closed its *stdin* and uses the read ends of the pipes instead.

Then I have a function to just kill the child:

```
void killChild(){
  printf("Killing %d\n", (int)childID);
  fflush(stdout);
  kill(childID, SIGKILL);
  waitpid(childID, NULL, 0);   // getting rid of the zombie
}
```

The child gets succesfully killed but the problem is that the **parent itself gets killed** as well. I checked the PID of the child and it's correct.

So why does the parent die?

Comment: I love the name of this question. And the art.

Comment: What signal did the parent receive?

Comment: Does the parent attempt to write to stdout or stderr after killing the child?  If so, it dies because of the SIGPIPE.  Are you changing handling of SIGCHLD?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Any attempt by the parent to write to its fd 1 or fd 2 after the child exits will result in the kernel sending SIGPIPE to the parent.  The default behavior for SIGPIPE is process termination.  That's probably what's happening.

Comment: That was indeed the problem. Just `close()`ing the pipes in the parent solved it. Now I just have to find a way to reset stdout and stderr.

Comment: @Pithikos dup() stdout/stderr before you create the pipes. After you closed the pipes, dup2() them back to file descriptor 1/2 again.

Answer (score 3):

You need to handle `SIGPIPE` and `SIGCHLD` signals - possibly just ignore them - and you should be fine.

Comment: And maybe it's a good idea to wait on terminated children, you know, the zombies ...